# Glide not loading ModelLoader factory

Tags: android, android-glide

I have created a AppGlideModule file for Glide and am replacing the registry with my own ModelLoader and factory. However, passing an instance (GlideModel) that I have the ModelLoader for does not load the ModelLoader, shown by debugging/log statements that aren't even hitting the interior of the ModelLoader. My proguard-rules are just

```
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl
```

and I can confirm that Glide is running and that it does run the registry replacement in registerComponents. Adding a request listener to the glide call also does not give an exception nor does changing the glide debug log level.

In the AppGlideModule I have:

```
 override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        val locallibFactory = LocallibFactory.Factory()
        registry.replace(GlideModel::class.java, InputStream::class.java, locallibFactory)
    }
```

LocallibFactory is

```
internal class LocallibFactory : ModelLoader<GlideModel, InputStream> {

    override fun handles(model: GlideModel): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun buildLoadData(
        model: GlideModel,
        width: Int,
        height: Int,
        options: Options
    ): ModelLoader.LoadData<InputStream>? {
        val key = ObjectKey("${model.book.filePath}:${model.position}")
        Timber.d("Got here")
        return ModelLoader.LoadData(key, LocallibDataFetcher(model))
    }

    internal class Factory : ModelLoaderFactory<GlideModel, InputStream> {

        override fun build(multiFactory: MultiModelLoaderFactory): ModelLoader<GlideModel, InputStream> {
            Timber.d("Got here2")
            return LocallibFactory()
        }

        override fun teardown() {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Glide is used in a fragment as

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(GlideModel(book, 0, true))
            .into(card.imageView)
```

But the timber log statements never hit and debugging shows it never goes in the LocallibFactory ModelLoader. This shouldn't happen with replace. Why would this ever happen and how can I get the ModelLoader to actually be called?

Answer (score 0):

Moved Glide call into presenter and it worked - probably a context issue?